# How to apply styles to the host-component of a FunctionComponent?

Tags: reactjs

If we have something like a card, we sometimes need to limit it's width.

If I am rendering the following component inside a flex-component, it would take up the entire space.

However, sometime I'd like to limit the width to, e.g., 10px.

How can I apply a style to the component if it's in use in any other component?

```js
const Card: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ padding: 8, border: '1px solid black' }}>
        <div>This is a test</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const StyledCard = styled(Test)`
  max-width: 10px;
`;
```

I am aware that I could do this via additional properties, but I was hoping that something like this does not require to have properties.

Comment: Won't this component be always inside another DOM element? In what case would it not be inside another component

Comment: Do you mean?

     const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
      max-width: 10px;
    `;

In that context why not scope to interpolate the component name?

Comment: React doesn't add an element to the DOM for the host component like for example Angular does, so there's no host DOM element to apply the style to. The only thing you can add a style to is the elements inside the template of the component through a property, or a wrapper element around the component.

Answer (score 0):

this working for my end:

```
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
    
    interface CardProps {
      applyStyle?: boolean;
    }
    
    const CardContainer = styled.div<{ applyStyle?: boolean }>`
      padding: 8px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      max-width: ${(props) => (props.applyStyle ? '10px' : 'none')};
    `;
    
    const Card: FunctionComponent<CardProps> = ({ applyStyle }) => {
      return (
        <CardContainer applyStyle={applyStyle}>
          <div>This is a test</div>
        </CardContainer>
      );
    };
    
    const StyledCard = styled(Card)`
      // Any additional styles you want to apply
    `;
    

// Usage:
// <Card /> // No style applied
// <StyledCard /> // Style applied with max-width: 10px;
```